# How to test callback functions with jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to create an asynchronous function that creates a file and test it with jest. At some point in my code, I call `write` from `CreateWriteStream` that takes a callback and jest is complaining about this function not being covered.

My function

```js
import { createWriteStream } from 'fs'
import { CreateFileStorage, CreateFileStorageModel } from '../../../../data/protocols/create-file-storage'

export class CreateFileLocalStorage implements CreateFileStorage {
  async create (fileData: CreateFileStorageModel): Promise<boolean> {
    return await new Promise((resolve) => {
      const ws = createWriteStream(fileData.path)

      ws.write(fileData.buffer, (err) => {
        if (err) resolve(false) // jest's saying 'if path not taken | statement not covered'

        resolve(true)
      })
    })
  }
}
```

And here is my test:

```js
import { existsSync, stat } from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import { CreateFileLocalStorage } from './file'

describe('Create File LocalStorage', () => {
  test('Should return false on failure', async () => {
    const createFileLocalStorage = new CreateFileLocalStorage()
    const buffer = Buffer.from('text to test')
    const file = {
      filename: 'test_file_creation.txt',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'test_file_creation.txt'),
      size: buffer.byteLength,
      buffer
    }

    // I don't know what to do here to get that 100% coverage
  })

  // I have one more test here that is working fine, it tests the happy path
})
```

My question is, how do I mock/test this code to get 100% coverage?

Because it is a callback function I don't know how to test this and it would be hard to purposefully create a failure there on the test

EDIT: I'm almost there and managed to make the test works with `jest.mock`, however now my second test is failing

```js
jest.mock('fs', () => {
  return {
    createWriteStream: () => {
      return {
        write: (chunk: any, callback?: (error: Error) => void): boolean => {
          callback(new Error())
          return false
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

describe('Create File LocalStorage', () => {
  test('Should return false on failure', async () => {
    const createFileLocalStorage = new CreateFileLocalStorage()
    const buffer = Buffer.from('text to test')
    const file = {
      filename: 'test_file_creation.txt',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'test_file_creation.txt'),
      size: buffer.byteLength,
      buffer
    }

    const promise = createFileLocalStorage.create(file)
    await expect(promise).resolves.toBeFalsy()
  })

  // this one now is failing, using `jest.clearMocks`
  // (actually any clear|reset jest function didn't work
  // the problem is that the module is still mocked at this point
  test('Should save file to disk on success', async () => {
    const createFileLocalStorage = new CreateFileLocalStorage()
    const buffer = Buffer.from('text to test')
    const file = {
      filename: 'test_file_creation.txt',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'test_file_creation.txt'),
      size: buffer.byteLength,
      buffer
    }

    const created = await createFileLocalStorage.create(file)
    expect(created).toBe(true)
    expect(existsSync(file.path)).toBe(true)

    stat(file.path, (err, status) => {
      expect(err).toBeNull()

      const isFile = status.isFile()
      const size = status.size

      expect(isFile).toBe(true)
      expect(size).toBe(file.size)
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`createWriteStream` returns an instance of the class `WriteStream`, so you may be able to mock the `write` instance method by spying on the prototype.

```
jest.spyOn(WriteStream.prototype, 'write').mockImplementation((buffer, cb) => {
  cb('this is an error')
})

expect(createFileLocalStorage.create('...')).resolves.toBeFalsy()
```

Comment: Almost there, spying WriteStream didn't work for me, but I managed to use jest.mock and make a slightly different mock compared with yours. My first test did work now, however, the second test is now failing, I tried to clear the mocks but to no avail.
Also, my `jest.mock` is on top of the file, if I move it to the test it fails